# Loop with iterators syntax VS Loop with generators syntax

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, generator

I noticed that a generator function returns an object which have .begin() and .end() methods. So I tried to use the classic syntax of iterators :

```
for (auto it = x.begin(), end = x.end(); it != end; ++it) { /**/ }
```

But I noticed that it doesn't work ... This is my code :

```
#include <experimental\generator>
using namespace std;

experimental::generator<int> test() {
    co_yield 0;
}

int main() {
    /*/
    // THIS LOOP MAKES PROGRAM CRASH
    for (auto it = test().begin(), end = test().end(); it != end; ++it)
        int a = *it;
    /*/
    // THIS LOOP WORKS
    for (auto i : test())
        int a = i;
    /**/

    return 0;
}
```

Is there something I don't know about generator loops and iterators syntax ? Is there a way to use the iterators syntax with the generators ?

Thanks for answer !

Comment: You're calling `test` multiple times, so you'll get a new generator every time. (`for (auto obj = test(), auto it = obj.begin(), end = obj.end(); it != end; ++it)`)

Comment: I don't know about generators, do each call to `test` return the same generator or different generator objects? If it returns different objects (which I guess i does), then their `begin` and `end` iterators will not be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noticed by Caramiriel and Some Programer Dude, I was instancing twice the generator. The following loop works :

```
auto gen = test();
for (auto it = gen.begin(), end = gen.end(); it != end; ++it)
    int a = *it;
```

Comment: Naming it `iterator` sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Yes if you're in a namespace (i.e. std::iterator) but here it is not a problem, it is just for the example ^^

Comment: No, it is a problem.  Like calling a variable of type `double` the name `integer` (when it has value `0.5`)

Comment: Oh ! I misunderstood you ^^' yes now that you mention it, it's clearly misnamed.